better approach for connected component analysis of image (with lots of text)
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("20240328_145148.jpg")
gray_img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (7,7),0)
plt.imshow(blurred)

threshold = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
analysis = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(threshold, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
(totalLabels, label_ids, values, centroid)= analysis


output = np.zeros(gray_img.shape, dtype="uint8")

for i in range(1, totalLabels):
    area = values[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]

    if(area<10000):
        componentMask = (label_ids == i).astype("uint8")*255
        output = cv2.bitwise_or(output, componentMask)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(output)


this is the code for the connected component analysis of an answer sheet image (with lots of text). i first tried it on a sample text image and worked fine. But with a single answer sheet image it is taking lot of time. Is there a more time-efficient method to do connected component analysis on such images

We can't tell you how to better process some image if we can't see the image -- [edit] your post and add an example input.

You are copying over the larger objects to a new image. This is the same as deleting the smaller objects. This is called an area opening. Find an implementation that you can call in one go, it’ll be very fast. Your code is slow because you iterate over the full image for each object you copy over, this is a lot of work when there are many objects! Existing implementations: skimage.morphology.area_opening, diplib.BinaryAreaOpening. OpenCV doesn’t have one AFAIK.

.astype("uint8")*255 is one extra step. just write .astype("uint8") or .astype(np.uint8)

@CrisLuengo OpenCV has cv2.morphologyEx() with the cv2. MORPH_OPEN operation. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

@beaker MORPH_OPEN does a structural opening (with a structuring element), not an area opening. There are many different types of opening. The opening is defined as any operation that is anti-extensive, absorbing and idempotent.

@CrisLuengo Cool, I'll read up!
